# XamarinUITest - Android WebView

Tags: testing, xamarin, xamarin.android, automated-tests, xamarin-studio

I want to automate an android application test and enter a text in an input field of a webview.
The authentication of the application is contained into an android webview.

I succedded on accessing the input field using (in my REPL console)

```
 app.Query(x => x.Css("#inputLogin"))
```

But this doesn't work. The android keyboard open, but no text is entered.

```
 app.EnterText(x => x.Css("#inputLogin"),"text")
```

Result form my query

```
>>> app.Query(x => x.Css("#inputLogin"))
Query for Css("#inputLogin") gave 1 results.
[
    [0] {
        Id => "inputLogin",
        NodeType => "ELEMENT_NODE",
        NodeName => "INPUT",
        Class => "form-control form-control--focusid ng-pristine ng-untouched ng
-valid ng-scope ng-empty",
        Html => "<input autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" type="text" clas
s="form-control form-control--focusid ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope
 ng-empty" id="inputLogin"  autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" ng-focus="model
.keypadVisible.cryptedPassword = false;" ng-model="model.email" af-validate="" a
f-validate-error-placeholder-id="loginError" af-validate-state-placeholder-id="l
oginSuccess" placeholder="N° Client Banque ou adresse e-mail" tabindex="1">",
        Value => null,
        WebView => "webView",
        TextContent => "",
        Rect => {
            Width => 930,
            Height => 135,
            CenterX => 540,
            CenterY => 510,
            Top => 124,
            Bottom => 0,
            Left => 25,
            Right => 0,
            X => 75,
            Y => 444
        }
    }
]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you are on the latest version of Xamarin .UITest, you might even try the latest beta/pre-release version on NuGet. I heard about issues with EnterText that should mostly have been resolved in the latest stable or perhaps beta version. Oh, and are you by chance using a Crosswalk WebView? IIRC there are some issues with Crosswalk webviews and input html input fields.

Comment: Thanks, i will investigate on that. I don't know about Crosswalk Webview, i'm testing an application which is not mine. I don't have access to the code.